# Python from color name to RGB

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, rgba

If I have a `function` which takes `color` as an input to be edited first (by RGB numbers), and then used in `matplotlib.pyplot`. How can I convert color name to RGB?

For example:

```
def function(color):
     color[3] = 0.5
     plt.plot([1,2],[2,4], color = color)
```

then `function((0,0,1,1))` works, but `function('blue')` will only work on the `plt.plot`.

How can I convert color name to RGB, (such as `blue` to `(0,0,1,1)`)?

Answer (score 45):

You can use with `matplotlib.colors`

```
from matplotlib import colors

print(colors.to_rgba('blue'))
```

Result:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: how to get the color name from rgb value in python?

Comment: Use the [CSS4_COLORS](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html) list from matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, by

```
from matplotlib import colors
orange_rgb = colors.hex2color(colors.cnames['orange'])
```