# Transparant, and coloured, networkx nodes with a node colour dictionary?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, draw, transparency

Whilst drawing a networkx graph, with differently coloured nodes, I'm trying to make some of them transparent. Based on the last [answer in this post](https://groups.google.com/g/networkx-discuss/c/Q9SHbJ4Af6A), that seems to be possible. However, I am experiencing some difficulties in setting both the colour, and the transparency value.

Analog to the given answer in the linked post, I tried:

```py
for node_name in G.nodes:
    if node_name[:4] == "red_":
        colour_dict[node_name] = ["olive",0.5]
    else:
        colour_dict[node_name] = ["yellow",1]
nx.draw(
        G,
        nx.get_node_attributes(G, "pos"),
        with_labels=True,
        node_size=160,
        font_size=6,
        width=0.2,
        node_color=color_map,
        edge_color=edge_color_map,
        # **options,
    )
```

Which returns:

> ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not [['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1], ['olive', 1]]

Hence, I would like to ask, how can one set the node colour and make it transparent (e.g. 50% transparent) at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives to the method you've chosen are described below:

1. Rather than searching for rgb values for your desired colors, you could use the method shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350872/python-from-color-name-to-rgb) to get the rgb value of the named color (just use `colors.to_rgb()` instead of `colors.to_rgba()` though), then append your desired alpha value to the end of the tuple using the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380860/add-variables-to-tuple).
2. It may be more convenient to draw the nodes separately using `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`  By doing so, you can pass in a list of colors to `node_color` and a list of alpha values to `alpha`.  With the `colour_dict` that you've defined, you can easily create these lists to pass into the drawing function.  You can find more details in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106232/change-networkx-graph-transparency-of-each-edge-and-node/74106862#74106862) if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to look up the rgb code of the colours I would like, (in range from 0-1 for red, 0-1 for green, 0-1 for blue), and set the node colour dict with a tuple instead of a list:

```py
  colour_dict[node_name] = (0,0,1,0.5)
```

for a blue node (red=0,green=0, blue=0), with a transparency of 50%.

[image]